# Need help writing simple callback function for Webtask

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to make a [webtask](https://webtask.io/docs/model) function of a node app I have working locally.  Webtask provides a template, which has a context (ctx) and a callback (cb) as the two arguments:

```
module.exports = function(ctx, cb) {
  cb(null, { hello: ctx.data.name || 'Anonymous' });
};
```

I have semi-working code that looks like this:

```
const PDFParser = require('pdf2json@1.1.7')
const request = require('request')

module.exports = function(ctx, cb) {

  const pdfParser = new PDFParser();
  const pdfUrl = ctx.body.data.url;
  const pdfPipe = request({url: pdfUrl, encoding:null}).pipe(pdfParser);
  const data = []; //define empty array for response data

  pdfPipe.on("pdfParser_dataError", err => console.error(err) );
  pdfPipe.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdf => {
    data.push(pdfParser.getAllFieldsTypes()); //push data into array
    console.log("data", data); //log the result
  });

  cb(null, data );
};
```

I need to send the updated "data" to the callback function, but cannot figure out how.  I am currently getting back an empty array (the initial `const data = []`), but my `console.log("data", data)` returns the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix your code, what you need to do is to invoke the callback when the on (emitter) is invoked:

```
const request = require('request')

module.exports = function(ctx, cb) {

  const pdfParser = new PDFParser();
  const pdfUrl = ctx.body.data.url;
  const pdfPipe = request({url: pdfUrl, encoding:null}).pipe(pdfParser);
  const data = []; //define empty array for response data

  pdfPipe.on("pdfParser_dataError", err => console.error(err) );
  pdfPipe.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdf => {
    data.push(pdfParser.getAllFieldsTypes()); //push data into array
    console.log("data", data); //log the result
    cb(null, data );
  });


};
```